# Alamofire timeout not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

In my app I am using Alamofire for network request and I created a class. Here is the class

```
class MGNetworking: NSObject{


    private class func getAlamofireManager() -> SessionManager  {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 180 // seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 180 // seconds

        let alamofireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

        return alamofireManager
    }

    class func requestGETURL(_ strURL: String, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void) {

        getAlamofireManager().request(strURL,method: .get).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                success(resJson)
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                failure(error)
            }
        }
    }



    class func requestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, headers : [String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){

        getAlamofireManager().request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                success(resJson)
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                failure(error)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want change timeout for my network request. I created method `getAlamofireManager()` but when I am calling this method my request cancelled here is the error.

```
FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
```

When I change `getAlamofireManager()` to `Alamofire.request`  it is start working perfect.

Comment: Don't forget the configuration object should be mutable (var) if you wish to set properties. Currently it is let.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can make an assumption that issue is connected with [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/157) reported problem.

So lets rewrite code:

```
class MGNetworking: NSObject{

 var manager: SessionManager?

 init() {
    manager = getAlamofireManager()
 }

  private class func getAlamofireManager() -> SessionManager  {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 180 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 180 // seconds

    let alamofireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

    return alamofireManager
}
}
```

So now use `manager` instead of the `getAlamofireManager()` for the requests

Comment: @pmb what url you are using ? Http or Https

Comment: I am using https